# I'm using selenium-java-4.1.2 jars with eclipse, I'm having issues launching chrome browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium-java-4.1.2 jars with eclipse, I'm having issues launching chrome browser... does anybody knows how to fix this?

my code
package SampleTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\Jars\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.get("www.google.com");
    
    driver.quit();
    
}
```

}

Starting ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.80 (7f0488e8ba0d8e019187c6325a16c29d9b7f4989-refs/branch-heads/4758@{#972}) on port 8244
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'WINDOWS-2AMSBIL', ip: '192.168.1.72', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at SampleTest.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:8244/status] to be available after 20016 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
... 10 more

Comment: What version of Chrome you have installed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.